# El buzón de correo no está disponible. La respuesta del servidor fue: \"JunkMail rejected

Tags: c#, .net

Buenas tardes, recurro a ustedes porque necesito algo de ayuda, estoy trabajando con .NET c# y trato de usar SmtpClient para enviar un mail.
El error que tengo es (El buzón de correo no está disponible. La respuesta del servidor fue: \"JunkMail rejected )
Aqui dejo mi avance.
Gracias en adelantado.

```
public void EnviarCorreo(string CorreoProveedor, string CorreoPersona, string Asunto, 
    string contenido, ref string output)
{

    if (CorreoPersona != "")
    {
        MailMessage mensaje = new MailMessage();
        mensaje.From = new MailAddress("nocontestar@metalcast.com.mx");
        mensaje.To.Add(new MailAddress(CorreoPersona)); //aqui he intentado con cuentas de 
        //@metalcast.com.mx y tambien con cuentas gmail pero ambas
        //dan el mismo error o tambien me marca 
        //"No se puede escribir datos       
        //de en la conexión de transporte: net_io_connectionclosed"
        mensaje.Subject = Asunto;//el valor que pongo es "Asunto"
        mensaje.Body = contenido;//aqui puse "contenido"
        mensaje.IsBodyHtml = false;        
        mensaje.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "metalcast.com.mx";
        smtp.Port = 25;
        smtp.EnableSsl = false;
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.Timeout = 10000;                
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("nocontestar@metalcast.com.mx", "psw");
        try
        {
            smtp.Send(mensaje);
            mensaje.Dispose();
            output = "Se ha enviado un correo exitosamente";
        }
        catch (Exception es)
        {
            mensaje.Dispose();
            output = es.Message;
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: Sería mejor que copiaras tu código y no una imagen de el .Gracias

Comment: hey @Luis, bienvenido, te parece si agregas los datos del servidor? Por cierto, date una vuelta por http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour y http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hola @Luis. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! No puedo ver bien esa imagen en el celular. ¿Podrías pegar el código **como texto**? Luego de pegarlo, hay que seleccionarlo y hacer click en el botón "{  }". Por otro lado, ¿a qué servidor te estás conectando? ¿es tuyo o es de un proveedor? ¿qué filtros de spam tiene activados? ¿tenés acceso al log del servidor de correos como para ver el error?

Comment: @Mariano, el servidor es mio, de hecho hace tiempo empece a tener un problema, cada que se envia un correo llega como spam, aun si es de mi mismo servidor y el log no marca nada.

Comment: acabo de darme cuenta que utilizas el puerto 26, hasta donde tengo entendido se utiliza el puerto 25. Lo has cambiado de manera manual?

Comment: Si el problema era el puerto

Answer (score 0):

Si estás utilizando **CPanel**:

Una probable solución:

1. Inicia sesion en el **WHM** con la cuenta **root**.
2. Ve a **Exim Configuration Manager**

Home »Service Configuration »Exim Configuration Manager

1. Click en Basic Editor
2. En esta  ventana, desmarca or selecciona off para todos RBLs, configura por defecto.
3. Guarda los cambios, ahora Exim se reiniciará
4. Revisa el servicio de correo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, gracias pero ya intente y no tengo nada de Exim RBL, sólo hay una sección con las ip bloqueadas pero no tengo ninguna.

Answer (score 0):

Los errores de tipo JunkMail Rejected pueden deberse a que tu servidor de correo está en una lista negra. ¿El error completo es de este tipo?

> Diagnostic-Code: smtp;550-"JunkMail rejected - col0-omc2-s3.col0.hotmail.com [63.53.38.73] is in an
>   550 RBL, see DNS queries to spamhaus.org zones not allowed"
>
> SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO::
>       host ejemplo.com [137.959.323.1]: 550-"JunkMail rejected - 
>       cloud3.ejemplos.com [92.19.79.31]: 33606 is
>      550 in an RBL, see Blocked - see http:/ /www.spamcop.net/bl.shtml?92.19.79.31

¿Has intentado utilizar tu código con otro servidor SMTP?